# set subfolder as domain in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have created the wordpress folder inside the root. Now I wanna to set it main domain.
for example.   my site url is  http://www.example.com
              wordpress url is http://www.example.com/wordpress

Now I wanna set wordpress as site url , it open with the main url

when I enter the http://www.example.com then it show me the wordrpess site that I have created, Please let me know how I can do it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+in+subfolder -> first hit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Pointing_your_home_site.27s_URL_to_a_subdirectory Learn to search, please.

Comment: wordpress is aleady in there, wanna set main domain. so user can see it when they enter main url http://www.example.com

Comment: And that’s exactly what the section on the WP site that I linked you to describes!

Answer (score 0):

Log into Wordpress and go to Settings -> General. Change Wordpress URL to be http://www.example.com/wordpress.

Log into FTP create workpress directory. Drag all wordpress related files to Wordpress directory.

Comment: already have wordpress. I want to show that when I enter the http://www.example.com

Comment: Like I said, log into your already existing wordpress and change the URL to be where you want it located. Then log into your FTP, create a wordpress directory and move the existing wordpress files to the wordpress directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```